# VBA loop range is too large - need alternative

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for assistance with the code below at the last section referenced as "Logic to calculate allocation".  I'm looking to conduct various sumifs divided by countifs for a range cells that span about 30k rows and over 20 columns.  I've tested it for just one column and it provided the results I expected but the time was a little less than reasonable.  I've modified the vba to run through all the cells in each column of the range but I have to shut it down since it has gone past 10 minutes with out an output.  I have read different solutions with regards to using arrays but that is something I have not learned and am having difficulty applying the concept of some of the solutions posted to this scenario.  I'm looking for improvements in this part of the logic to help with the efficiency and time of the output.  Thanks ahead of time.

```
Sub Alloc_Entity()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False




'-----Logic to calculate allocation---------

Dim GLcell As Range, GLAllocRg As Range, c As Range


    Set GLAllocRg = MainWk.Range(MainWk.Cells(fRow, fGLCol), MainWk.Cells(lRow, lCol)) '------used for testing

    For Each c In GLAllocRg
        c = ((WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(AmtRg, TypeRg, "Entity", TransGLRg, MainWk.Cells(GLrow, c.Column).Value, EntPIRLocRg, "Acquisition Company", EntPIRValueRg, MainWk.Cells(c.Row, AcqCoCol).Value) / WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(AcqCoRg, MainWk.Cells(c.Row, AcqCoCol).Value))) _
        + (WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(AmtRg, TypeRg, "Entity", TransGLRg, MainWk.Cells(GLrow, c.Column).Value, EntPIRLocRg, "Property Manager", EntPIRValueRg, MainWk.Cells(c.Row, PMCol).Value) / WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(PMRg, MainWk.Cells(c.Row, PMCol).Value)) _
        + (WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(AmtRg, TypeRg, "Entity", TransGLRg, MainWk.Cells(GLrow, c.Column).Value, EntPIRLocRg, "Market", EntPIRValueRg, MainWk.Cells(c.Row, MarketCol).Value) / WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(MarketRg, MainWk.Cells(c.Row, MarketCol).Value)) _
        + (WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(AmtRg, TypeRg, "Entity", TransGLRg, MainWk.Cells(GLrow, c.Column).Value, EntPIRLocRg, "State", EntPIRValueRg, MainWk.Cells(c.Row, StateCol).Value) / WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(StateRg, MainWk.Cells(c.Row, StateCol).Value))

    Next






Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Code optimization is better suited for coderview. And frankly, this is too much code. you should reduce it just the bare minimum that shows your problem.

Comment: Suggestion: time the individual parts.  How long does it take between each `'-----` line?  Is one of the `For Each` loops slower than the others?  Also, print the number of cells you have to process to see where you can get the most bang for the buck.

Comment: Also, if all you're doing is finding cells and then applying worksheet functions based on those cells, you might well be able to eliminate the VBA and do all the computation on-worksheet using `VLOOKUP` and friends.  I suspect that would be faster, but don't know for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  The issue is in the last For Each loop under the section ----Logic to calculate allocation-----.  The other sections above are declaring ranges, variables and worksheets.

Comment: I've modified the code to just so the problem area.  All the ranges are located in another worksheet with the exception of the ranges for the countifs.  All criteria for sumifs and the range/criteria under the countifs are located on the "MainWk" where the calculation is being conducted in the GLAllocRg.

Comment: If you're interested in feedback on any/all aspects of your code, including but not limited to performance, readability and maintainability, bring the full code over to [codereview.se], we'll happily <s>shred it to pieces</s> help you improve it! =)

Comment: `"sumifs divided by countifs"`  that sounds like `AVERAGEIFS` to me.